# App crashing while trying to add a marker programmatically based on the coordinates stored in FirebaseDatabase

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, nullpointerexception, google-maps-markers

I have a button which when clicked saves user's coordinates to `FirebaseDatabase` and also open another activity and in this other activity I fetch the saved coordinates and show `Markers` on a Map based on them.

The problem is that when I'm pressing this button from 1st device of mine, the marker is getting shown on the map in second activity. Now, when I press this button from 2nd device of mine (keeping this activity opened in 1st device too), the app crashes in the 1st device giving this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference` but both the markers are shown on the map in the 2nd device and app does not gets crashed there.

This is how I'm saving the coordinates:

```
aUserReference.child(requestID.getText().toString()).child(MainActivity.uid).child("currentLngOfUser").setValue(String.valueOf(MainActivity.currentLngDouble));
```

and this how I'm fetching them and trying to show on map:

```
    aUserReference.child(requestID).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        Map<String, String> newAUser = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        pAccepted = newAUser.get("name");
                        uidPPlayer = newAUser.get("dpUrl");
                        // error on the line below
                        currentLtAU = Double.parseDouble(newAUser.get("currentLatOfUser"));
                        currentLnAU = Double.parseDouble(newAUser.get("currentLngOfUser"));


                        playerMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLtAU, currentLnAU)).title(pAccepted));

                        markersList.add(playerMarker);

                        //        //get the latLngbuilder from the marker list
                        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                        for (Marker m : markersList) {
                            builder.include(m.getPosition());
                        }

                        //Bounds padding here
                        int padding = 100;

                        //Create bounds here
                        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

                        //Create camera with bounds
                        final CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);

                        //Check map is loaded
                        mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onMapLoaded() {
                                //animate camera here
                                mMap.animateCamera(cu);
                //                mMap.isMyLocationEnabled();
                //                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                            }
                        });

                        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        prepareDataAcceptedPlayers();
                    } else {
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                .make(coordinatorLayout, "Some error occurred. Please retry!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.show();
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

full stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.abc.xxx, PID: 3946
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
                      at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:263)
                      at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                      at com.abc.xxx.ARequest$5.onChildAdded(ARequest.java:352)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajg.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalg.zzcxk(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalj$1.run(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5318)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:922)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:717)
```

Please let me know what is going wrong here and why am I getting a `nullpointerexception` when there is something stored in that reference.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace please ?

Comment: @rhari done. Please check out the edited question

Comment: When the button is pressed on the second device, does it override the location that is read by the first device ? I think MainActivity.currentLngDouble is the issue : can you equate this to "" (empty string) where it is declared and try again ?

Comment: I don't know if it overrides, but I am able to see 2 different markers on 2 different locations on map in 2nd device and `MainActivity.currentLngDouble` is a `double` value. 

Hey.. please see the edited part of the question (2nd paragraph from above)

Comment: Ok so initialize it to 0 before it is sent

Comment: same error even after initialising `MainActivity.currentLngDouble = 0.0` in the `MainActivity` and able to see both the markers properly on the map in the 2nd device!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129116/discussion-between-rhari-and-hammad-nasir).